# Интервал между датами с определенным шагом

Tags: c#

Как получить интервал между датами от сегодняшнего дня до заданного.

Есть три диапазона:

- интервал год с шагом 1 месяц,
- месяц с шагом 1 день,
- день с шагом 1 час.

Я делаю так:

Пусть TimeInterval = 2.

```
var timeStart= DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-item.TimeInterval);
var timeFinish = DateTime.Now;

var interval = timeFinish - timeStart;

var days = from shift in Enumerable.Range(0, interval.Days)
    select @timeStart.AddDays(shift);

var hours = from shift in Enumerable.Range(0, Convert.ToInt32(interval.TotalHours))
    select @timeStart.AddHours(shift);
```

**Как сделать для 2 лет с шагом в 1 месяц???**

Потом я хочу в цикле знать дату каждого диапазона.

Например для года:

```
2017-01-01 00:00:00 - 2017-01-31 23:59:59
2017-02-01 00:00:00 - 2017-02-28 23:59:59
2017-03-01 00:00:00 - 2017-03-31 23:59:59
...
2018-08-01 00:00:00 - 2018-08-31 23:59:59
```

Для 2 месяцев:

```
2018-07-01 00:00:00 - 2018-07-01 23:59:59
2018-07-02 00:00:00 - 2018-07-02 23:59:59
2018-07-03 00:00:00 - 2018-07-03 23:59:59
...
2018-08-21 00:00:00 - 2018-08-21 23:59:59
```

Для 2 дней:

```
2018-08-20 00:00:00 - 2018-08-20 00:59:59
2018-08-20 01:00:00 - 2018-08-20 01:59:59
2018-08-20 02:00:00 - 2018-08-20 02:59:59
...
2018-08-20 23:00:00 - 2018-08-20 23:59:59
```

Comment: [TimeSpan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) - попробуйте!

Comment: Ничего не понял

Comment: @Monomax, разница дат и есть TimeSpan

Comment: @АндрейNOP Как сделать из диапазона в 2 года с шагом в 1 месяц? Ведь TimeSpan инициализирует количество часов, минут и секунд.

Comment: *Как сделать из диапазона в 2 года с шагом в 1 месяц?* – сделать что? Что у вас имеется на входе и какой должен быть вывод?

Comment: @АндрейNOP имеется диапазон timeStart-timeFinish, к примеру `2016-01-01 00:00:00 - 2018-08-01 00:00:00`. На выходе должен быть каждый месяц, интервалы `2016-01-01 00:00:00 - 2016-01-31 23:59:59` и т.д.
`2017-03-01 00:00:00 - 2017-03-31 23:59:59`

Answer (score 2):

Простой универсальный генератор диапазонов на кортежах может выглядеть так:

```
IEnumerable<(DateTime Start, DateTime End)> EnumerateRanges(DateTime startDate, 
    DateTime endDate, int months = 0, int days = 0, int hours = 0)
{
    DateTime start = startDate;
    DateTime next = start.AddMonths(months).AddDays(days).AddHours(hours);
    while (next <= endDate)
    {
        yield return (start, next.AddSeconds(-1));
        start = next;
        next = start.AddMonths(months).AddDays(days).AddHours(hours);
    }
    yield return (start, endDate);
}
```

Интервал, как не сложно заметить, можно выбирать на любой вкус. Последний интервал может измеряться даже тиками, тут уж как конечную дату зададите. Естественно в генераторе необходимы проверки на то, что длина указанных интервалов не отрицательна, что начальная дата меньше конечной и прочие защитные приемы, но это уже сами допишете.

Использование:

```
var start = new DateTime(2001,1,1);
var end = new DateTime(2003,1,15);
foreach(var range in EnumerateRanges(start, end, months: 2, hours: 1)) 
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{range.Start} - {range.End}");
}
```

Если не нравятся кортежи, можете заменить своим классом и заполнять его экземпляр в генераторе вместо кортежа.

Answer (score 0):

Заведите структуру с названием, например `DateTimeSpan` 
с двумя полями начало периода и конец, публичным свойством `TimeSpan Duration`, и методом `ToString()`. Ну и совсем тем, что ещё вам понадобиться.

```
public struct DateTimeSpan
{
   public DateTime Start {get;}
   public DateTime Finish {get;}
   public DateTimeSpan (DateTime start, DateTime finish)
   {
       Start = start;
       Finish = finish;
   }

   public TimeSpan Duration => Finish - Start;
   public override string ToString() => $"{Finish} - {Start}";

}
```

А генерировать коллекцию можно и через `for`

Comment: TimeSpan инициализирует количество часов, минут и секунд. А как получить месяцы? Хочу именно диапазон разделить по месяцам

Comment: @Barlukov, А если ровно не разобьётся, куда остаток девать?